# __func__ in linux vs __FUNCTION__ in VS

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2008, gcc

```
class A 
{
 public:
 void Print()
 {
   #if defined( win32 )
   std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
   #else
   std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
   #endif
 }
};

int main()
{
 A ob;
 ob.Print();
 return 0;
}
```

The above code snippet prints `A::Print` in Windows and `Print` in Linux.
What's the way to get the the `classname::functionname` in Linux ?

Comment: gcc has `__FUNCTION__` macro. Also, you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, it's not the same as `__FUNCTION__`, since `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains parameter-clause too.

Comment: Looks like __FUNCTION__ in gcc also gives just the function name and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ returns the entire function signature :( My requirement is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no macro, you are looking for. But you may easily do it from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` like:

```
inline std::string 
method_name (const std::string &fsig)
{
  size_t colons = fsig.find ("::");
  size_t sbeg = fsig.substr (0, colons).rfind (" ") + 1;
  size_t send = fsig.rfind ("(") - sbeg;
  return fsig.substr (sbeg, send) + "()";
}

#define __METHOD_NAME__ method_name (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
```

And then use like:

```
#if defined (win32)
std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
#else
std::cout << __METHOD_NAME__ << std::endl;
#endif
```

To get identical results